# Count the number of lines in a large number (100k+) of files

Tags: bash

I tried using `wc -l`, but it says `Argument list too long`. Is there an alternative? The total number of files in the directory is 100k+ and there are too many lines per file as well (200k+ in each).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a separate count for each file, do:

```
find /dir -exec wc -l {} +
```

`-exec +` is smart and will call `wc` multiple times with partial file lists so as not to exceed the OS's command line length limit.

If you want one combined count for all files, do:

```
find /dir -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

By concatenating all of the files together only one `wc` invocation is needed.